# Javascript/Nodejs Move a lot of function that modified internal state in an external file

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object with a lot o function that can modify the internal state and i want to move all this function in an external file. There is a best practise to do this?
The main object is the Airplane and when the airplane fly a lot of situation can happens. For every situation i have a function that do something that change the internal state of the airplane (a.e. change the current speed of an engine). These function are named situation1, situation2, ... situationN.
I want to put all these function in a kind o library. Is this correct and/or possible? 
THis is an example code

```
function Engine(){
    this.state = 'off';
    this.currentSpeed = 0;
}

function Airplane(){
    this.engine1 = new Engine();
    this.engine2 = new Engine();
}

Airplane.prototype.fly = function(){
    //this is for example
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
    switch (randomnumber) {
        case 1: this.situation1();break;
        case 2: this.situation2();break;
        // ...
        case 100: this.situation100();break;            
    }
    this.fly();
}

Airplane.prototype.situation1 = function() { /*change internal state of an Engine* a.e: */ this.engine1.currentSpeed = '200'; }
Airplane.prototype.situation2 = function() { /*change internal state of Engine* a.e: */ this.engine1.currentSpeed = 200 * 3.14; }
// ...
Airplane.prototype.situation100 = function()  { /*change internal state of Engine*/ this.engine2.state = 'on';}


airplane = new Airplane();
airplane.fly();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I believe you're looking for is what node.js refers to as a "module" which is explained in http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

One way to do this would be to create a new file called "Airplane.js" which contains:

```
// define your main object
var Airplane = function(){
    // initialize it here
};

Airplane.funcOne=function(){ // "class" level function
};

Airplane.prototype.funcTwo=function(){ // "instance" level function
};

// assign Airplane to module exports 
module.exports=Airplane;

// which allows you to:
//     var Airplane=require('Airplane');
```

If you do not expect to use your Engine in other code, you can define it in the Airplane.js.

If you expect you will need to 'require' it from other code, you'd want to place it into it's own file and 'require' it in Airplane.js, like:

```
// Engine.js
var Engine=function(){
};

module.exports=Engine;

// Airplane.js
var Engine=require('Engine');

var Airplane=function(){
};

module.exports=Airplane;
```

Finally, if you want to expose both Airplane and Engine from the same file, you can:

```
var Engine=function(){
};

var Airplane=function(){
};

module.exports={
    Engine:   Engine,
    Airplane: Airplane
};
```

So that when you require Airplane in another file, you'd say:

```
var Airplane = require('Airplane').Airplane,
    Engine   = require('Airplane').Engine;
```

#### Update

For the record, I don't favor defining an object's prototype methods outside of the file which defines the object, but having said that...

Adding methods defined in another file to an existing object requires that you 'require' the additional file, iterate over its functions, and add them to the existing object.

The easiest way to do this would be to define your methods as:

```
// file: AirplaneMethods.js

module.exports={

    // what occurs in situation1
    situation1: function(){

        // as expected, 'this' within this method refers 
        // to the object into which this method is "imported."

        return this; // to facilitate method chaining
    },

    // what occurs in situation2
    situation2: function(){
        // ...
        return this; 
    }

    // etc.
};
```

Then, to add these methods to your Airplane object, you would:

```
var Airplane=function(){
    // initialization
};

var importedMethods=require('AirplaneMethods');

for(var methodName in importedMethods) {
    Airplane.prototype[methodName]=importedMethods[methodName];
}
```

Or for a more general solution:

```
/* Import.js -- 20130712 raisch
 *
 * imports methods defined in one or more external paths into an
 * existing object's prototype
 *
 * Usage:
 *
 *     var Import=require('Import');
 *
 *     var Thing=function() {};
 *
 *     Import.from(path1,path2,...).into(Thing);
 *
 *     -or-
 *
 *     Import.into(Thing).from(path1,path2,...)
 *
 */

var util=require('util'),
    assert=require('assert');

var Import=module.exports=function(){};

Import._target=null;

Import._libs={};

// shortcut
var hasOwnProperty=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

// helper
function isEmpty(obj){
    var result=true;
    if(obj===null || 0===obj.length) {
        result=true;
    }
    else if(obj.length && obj.length>0) {
        result=false;
    }
    else {
        for(var k in obj) {
            if(hasOwnProperty.call(obj,k)) {
                result=false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * requires one or more libs, caching them into self._libs
 *
 * if self._target is not null, calls self.into() to add all lib
 * methods to self._target.prototype
 *
 * @param paths {Array<String>}
 * @returns {Object} self
 */
Import.from=function from(/*path,...*/){
    var paths=Array.prototype.slice(arguments);
    for(var i=0, len=paths.length; i<len; i++){
        var path=paths[i],
            lib=null;
        try{
            lib=require(path);
            if(isEmpty(lib)){
                throw 'requiring "'+path+'" did not produce a useful object';
            }
        }
        catch(e){
            console.error('Import.from failed to require path "%s":%s', path, e);
            continue;
        }
        this._libs[path]=lib;
    }
    this._target && this.into(this._target);
    return this;
};

/**
 * sets target object (class) into which to import lib methods
 *
 * if self._libs is not empty, adds all lib methods to self._target.prototype
 *
 * @param target {Object} into which to import
 * @returns {Object} self
 */
Import.into=function into(target){
    assert.ok(target.prototype, 'Import.into: target must have a prototype');
    this._target=target;
    if(!isEmpty(this._libs)){
        for(var libname in this._libs){
            var lib=this._libs[libname];
            for(var name in lib){
                this._target.prototype[name]=lib[name];
            }
        }
    }
    return this;
};

/**
 * clears library cache
 * @returns {Object} self
 */
Import.clear=function clear(){
    this._libs={};
    return this;
};

/**
 * clears library cache and target object
 * @returns {Object}
 */
Import.reset=function reset(){
    delete this._target;
    this.clear();
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but maybe i have'nt explained well what's the problem. I would like to put all Airplane.prototype.situationX functions in a external file, doing a kind of library that can change the Airplane status when called in the fly function.

Comment: You would do this by putting the definition of your Airplane object into its own file. Is your intent to put all of the Airplane.prototype functions into their own file only? If so, I'll edit my answer to show this can be done as well.

Comment: yes, i would like to put all Airplane.prototype functions into their own file because they are 100 functions.